# Transparency within instanced shapes

Tags: three.js

I've been playing with `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry`. I finally got an example to work, and have now been playing with the shader. The first thing I tried was setting transparency. My example code is below.

The initial state, and from a host of other camera angles (e.g. drag your mouse to the left), the transparency doesn't seem to have any effect. But then at other camera angles (e.g. reload and drag your mouse to the right), the shapes clearly overlap, which is what I was expecting.

Is depth-sorting handled differently for instanced shapes, or am I doing something wrong, or missing something? Do I somehow need to update the shapes so the camera knows their proper depth in the scene?

```js
var cubeGeo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10));
//cubeGeo.maxInstancedCount = 8;

cubeGeo.addAttribute("cubePos", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  25, 25, 25,
  25, 25, -25, -25, 25, 25, -25, 25, -25,
  25, -25, 25,
  25, -25, -25, -25, -25, 25, -25, -25, -25
]), 3, 1));

var vertexShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;",
  "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;",
  "",
  "attribute vec3 position;",
  "attribute vec3 cubePos;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( cubePos + position, 1.0 );",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");
var fragmentShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");

var mat = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {},
  vertexShader: vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
  transparent: true
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, mat);

scene.add(mesh);
```

```css
html * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#host {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<div id="host"></div>

<script>
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    FOV = 35,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 1000;

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  document.getElementById('host').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);


  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.position.z = 250;

  var trackballControl = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  trackballControl.rotateSpeed = 2.0; // need to speed it up a little

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera.add(light);

  scene.add(light);

  function render() {
    if (typeof updateVertices !== "undefined") {
      updateVertices();
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    trackballControl.update();
    render();
  }

  animate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `InstancedBufferGeometry` with meshes that are translucent.

The instances are rendered in the order they appear in the buffer. The faces of each instance are rendered in the ordered specified by the geometry.

Consequently, if you use instancing with translucency, you will likely have artifacts depending on the viewing angle.

Depending on your use case, you can try setting `material.depthWrite = false`, but that can lead to other artifacts.

If your mesh textures have areas of complete transparency (rather than partial) you should be able to use `material.alphaTest` to discard unwanted fragments without artifacts.

three.js r.84

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the only *real* way to make this work would be to rearrange my `cubePos` buffer in a depth-sorted manner, correct? And including such a per-frame task would probably kill any performance benefits gained by using instances (although memory would still benefit). :(

Comment: Don't resort the geometry faces: use the back-face-front-face trick implemented [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_convex.html).  You may have to reorder the instances, though.

Comment: We're on the same page regarding not altering the geometry. `cubePos` *is* my instances, and I actually got it to work that way--it's just inefficient (I'll post an answer with that code). I'll try the back-face-front-face trick, though I'm not as keen on it due to adding more meshes to the scene.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion with WestLangley in the comments, I added a sorter for my instances. It sorts the instances positions based on their distance from the camera.

(Side-note: If I had any other `THREE.InstancedBufferAttributes` I would need to re-order them at the same time.)

The biggest downside to this is that it becomes more and more expensive as the scene gets bigger, both in instanced and non-instanced shapes.

```js
// Instances Sorter, called each frame
function sortObjectInstances(obj) {
  if (obj.geometry) {
    if (obj.geometry instanceof THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry) {
      var array = obj.geometry.attributes.cubePos.array,
        vecArray = [];
      for (var i = 0, l = array.length / 3; i < l; ++i) {
        vecArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(array[(i * 3)], array[(i * 3) + 1], array[(i * 3) + 2]));
      }
      vecArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.distanceTo(camera.position) > b.distanceTo(camera.position)) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.distanceTo(camera.position) < b.distanceTo(camera.position)) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      for (var i = 0, l = vecArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
        array[(i * 3)] = vecArray[i].x;
        array[(i * 3) + 1] = vecArray[i].y;
        array[(i * 3) + 2] = vecArray[i].z;
      }
      obj.geometry.attributes.cubePos.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, l = obj.children.length; i < l; ++i) {
      sortObjectInstances(obj.children[i]);
    }
  }
}

var cubeGeo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10));
//cubeGeo.maxInstancedCount = 8;

cubeGeo.addAttribute("cubePos", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  25, 25, 25,
  25, 25, -25, -25, 25, 25, -25, 25, -25,
  25, -25, 25,
  25, -25, -25, -25, -25, 25, -25, -25, -25
]), 3, 1));

var vertexShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;",
  "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;",
  "",
  "attribute vec3 position;",
  "attribute vec3 cubePos;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( cubePos + position, 1.0 );",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");
var fragmentShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");

var mat = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {},
  vertexShader: vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
  transparent: true
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, mat);

scene.add(mesh);
```

```css
html * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#host {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<div id="host"></div>

<script>
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    FOV = 35,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 1000;

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  document.getElementById('host').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);


  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.position.z = 250;

  var trackballControl = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  trackballControl.rotateSpeed = 2.0; // need to speed it up a little

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera.add(light);

  scene.add(light);

  function render() {
    if (typeof sortObjectInstances !== "undefined") {
      sortObjectInstances(scene); // Sort the instances
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    trackballControl.update();
    render();
  }

  animate();
</script>
```

Comment: A minor efficiency change would be to store the array of `THREE.Vector3` objects on the mesh its self, rather than generating it each time.