# With Instancing, I am not able to change the transparency/opacity of the individual child geometries

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, buffer-geometry, geometry-instancing

I have a simple model consisting of 1000 instances of sphere. I am trying to use instancing to reduce the number of draw calls. However, I am not able to change the transparency/opacity of the individual child geometries.

I already tried the following things:

I am able to change transparency of every sphere using

```
material.fragmentShader = "varying vec3 vColor;void main() {  gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 0.2 );}";
```

However, that changes the opacity to 0.2 for every sphere.

The html file is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A-Frame Instancing component</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A-Frame Instancing component">
    <script>
    /*
    var WebVRConfig = {
        FORCE_ENABLE_VR: true,
        BUFFER_SCALE: 1.0
    };
    */
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/v0.4.0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.2.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="build/aframe-instancing.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene stats>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="sky" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/examples/primitives/models/peach-gradient.jpg">
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity instancing="count:100"></a-entity>
      <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
      <a-entity light="type:directional;color:#FFFFFF" position="-1 1 1"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

The function to acheive instancing:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('instancing', {
      schema: {
        count: {type: 'int', default: 10000}
      },

        var geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
        geometry.copy(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(5.0));


        var translateArray = new Float32Array(count*3);
        var vectorArray = new Float32Array(count*3);
        var colorArray = new Float32Array(count*3);

         geometry.addAttribute('translate', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(translateArray, 3, 1));
        geometry.addAttribute('vector', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(vectorArray, 3, 1));
        geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(colorArray, 3, 1));

         var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
          uniforms: {
            time: {value: 0}
          },
          vertexShader: [
            'attribute vec3 translate;',
            'attribute vec3 vector;',
            'attribute vec3 color;',
            'uniform float time;',
            'varying vec3 vColor;',
            'const float g = 9.8 * 1.5;',
            'void main() {',
            '  vec3 offset;',
            '  offset.xz = vector.xz * time;',
            '  offset.y = vector.y * time - 0.5 * g * time * time;',
            '  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position + translate + offset, 1.0 );',
            '  vColor = color;',
        '}'
          ].join('\n'),
          fragmentShader: [
            'varying vec3 vColor;',
            'void main() {',
            '  gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1 );',
            '}'
          ].join('\n')
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        this.model = mesh;
        el.setObject3D('mesh', mesh);

        el.emit('model-loaded', {format:'mesh', model: mesh});
        //try to change opacity here
        material.fragmentShader = "varying vec3 vColor;void main() {  gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 0.2 );}";

        material.transparent = true;

        //use the new opacity
        var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material);
        this.mesh = mesh1;
        el.setObject3D('mesh', mesh1);
        el.emit('model-loaded', {format:'mesh', model: mesh1});
      }   
    });
 }
 ]);
```

Can anyone please tell me, how to change opacity of only one sphere?  Thank you in advance!

Also, suppose I am trying to replicate multiple boxes.
One of which is as following:

```
    <a-box position="19.0 1.5 23.0"
           width="32.0"
           height="1.0"
           depth="40.0"
           color="#969696"
           shader="flat"
           flat-shading="true">
    </a-box>
```

What would be the values I would fill in translateArray & vectorArray ? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colors are only `RGB` values, not `RGBA`. Update your `color` attribute to support 4 values, and change associated `vec3` references to use `vec4`. The last value in the vector will be your `alpha` (transparency) value.

It looks like you already know how to send the value from your `vertex shader` into your `fragment shader`, so I won't go into detail there. But in your `fragment shader`, you can use the color directly, because `gl_FragColor` expects to be set to a `vec4`.

**Further clarification:**

When you create a `InstancedBufferAttribute`, you create one attribute *per instance*. So your `color` attribute currently only carries `RGB` values for each instance.

Hard-coding `1` or `0.2` in the `w` place (i.e. `gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1 );`), you apply it universally to all instances. So, you need to define the `alpha` value on a per-instance basis, and the easiest way to do this is through your already-created and instanced `color` attribute.

```
//geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(colorArray, 3, 1)
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(colorArray, 4, 1)
```

The code above makes room for the alpha values, which you should supply for each sphere. Your `colorArray` will contain data like `[ R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A, ... ]`.

Then, in your shaders...

```c
// vertex shader
// ...
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 vColor;
// ...
void main(){
  // ...
  vColor = color;
  // ...
}
```

```c
// fragment shader
// ...
varying vec4 vColor;
// ...
void main(){
  // ...
  gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Now, the alpha value that you supplied for each sphere instance will be used only for that instance. For example, if you want the sphere at index 1 to be the only transparent sphere, your `colorArray` buffer should look like this:

```
colorArray = [
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  // ...
];`
```

**Important caveat**

This implementation does not depth-sort the instances, and so blending will be dependent on render order. You can read more about this in the following question:

[Transparency within instanced shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502415/transparency-within-instanced-shapes)

Comment: I understand the fourth item is the alpha value. My question is, Is it possible to change the transparency of only one sphere, without changing it for others? Buffer-geometry does not allow this, is it possible with instancing? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar I've added more information to clarify the point. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It explains a lot :)

Comment: I added a little doubt in my question at the end. Can you please clarify that as well? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @ShubhamKumar I'm guessing that is aframe? I really know nothing about that. Also, it seems like a separate issue deserving of a separate question. Be sure to tag aframe as well. :)